# I need to use a method in a VB file in my C# program, how can I call this method?

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll

I have a file coded in VB that I need to reference and use in my C# program.  I am having trouble getting my C# program to recognize my .vb file so that I can send variables to it through C# windows form methods.  How can I get these 2 files to work together?  do I need to include a using statement combined with a system method?  What do you suggest?

Comment: No, you need to compile it to a dll, and reference that.

Comment: Is it to much to simply rewrite the VB code into c#? If it is, then simply recompile it as a .dll as ofstream suggested.

Comment: if you have the vb project compiled as a dll, you can add the dll as a project reference and then that combined with a using statment should make the public classes from the dll accessable in the c# code.  from there, work as normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a VB.NET new project
2. Add your VB file into it.
3. Compile the project and get the DLL from `bin` folder.
4. Add a reference to this DLL in your C# project.
5. Now you can access the functions of VB file.

Alternately, you can add both your C# and this new VB project in a single solution and add a reference to VB project in your C# project. This is the preferred solution from debugging point of view.

You may want to try freely available conversion tools that can convert your VB.NET code to C# code (and vice versa) that will get you rid of all of the above. I regularly use the excellent conversion tool called Econ NetVert available [here](http://econnetvert.codeplex.com/).

I just noted that you have added VB6 as one of the tags in your question. Is the code in question in VB6? If so, you may first need to upgrade it to VB.NET. I know there was a wizard in VS2003 that could do this for you. Not sure if there's any other equivalent tool or method in VS2010 or VS2012 now-a-days.

Comment: +1 For suggesting the same solution with two projects vs compiling to DLL. It's the much better solution, especially if the logic in the VB code is complicated